# How do you draw a x-bar tree with negative inversion?

Tags: syntax, grammar, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory, transformations

For example: 'Never was I so offended'

There is already a T to C inversion with 'was', where do we put the word 'Never'?

And how should we label it? AdvP or Neg?